# My Inherited Process Template named SCRUMUA in my one VSTS account didn't get exported to my another VSTS Account

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I installed the NP M through the “node-v8.11.3-x64” from your link and it installed successfully.
Then I create the PAT from both the Source VSTS account and from the Target VSTS account.
Then I manually created the Configuration.json file.
The Configuration.json file is in the attachments for your review, I changed the PATs from it for security reason.
Then I ran the Node.Exe file.
Command Prompt open and there I ran the command

```
 process-migrator [--mode=<migrate(default)/import/export> [--config=]
```

Which I ran on my machine like this:-

```
process [export [--config=C:\Users\uabbasi\Documents\configuration.json]
```

But the TFS Process Template named SCRUMUA didn’t get exported to Target VSTS account.

I think the command I am running is incorrect so can you please let me know how to correct this command And if something else is missing or incorrect then can you please do let me know that.

If possible can you please share any video or stepbystep guide regarding how to use this process migrator which shall by very helpful for us.

The node.exe command prompt image present below and command that i ran which didn't work.

process-migrator_command_running_through_node exe_on_comand_prompt

[image]

Configuration.json file image that i have created and using it :

[image]

YOU CAN ALSO SEE MY POST THAT I FIRST POSTED ON THE "MICROSOFT / PROCESS-MIGRATOR SITE.  Its link is also present below :

https://github.com/Microsoft/process-migrator/issues/18

Thanks,
Umair Abbasi.

Answer (score 0):

Check my steps below:

1. Download and install node-v8.11.3-x64 as you did.
2. Open cmd and run `npm install process-migrator -g`.

[image]

3. Create and fill required information in config file *configuration.json*.

[image]

4. Run `process-migrator --mode=export --config=C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\process-migrator\configuration.json` to export the process template.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your support and quick reply.